# Flex-AS3 weired issue with Point

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I was trying to convert global coordinates to local coordinates of a UIComplenent in my flex project using below code using below code

```
var gp:Point = new Point(e.stageX,e.stageY);  //global point
var lp:Point = uic.globalToLocal(gp); //local point
```

uic is UIComponent in which I have subclass of Sprite for drawing something

**I have set the sprite's mouseEnabled and mouseChildren to false to not interrupt the mouse event.**

above code is within uic's mousemove event where I was tracing the gp and lp gp was giving correct value and suprisingly lp was giving negetive values. when I move the move to the top left corner of uic i expect lp to be 0,0 but it is giving the -width of of uic. I broke my head for hours and ended up finding an alternate by using offsets. Infact my original code was much simpler like this which was same issue

```
var lp:Point = new Point(e.localX,e.localY);
```

I am not sure what exactly is causing this problem. the workaround had lot of issues and it creating a mess in my rest of the algorithms.

Just now I found even more interesting thing (which is actually weird). for some reason I went and create a new lp2

```
var lp2:Point = new Point(e.localX,e.localY);
```

now surprisingly it was giving correct values as expected and I went back and changed the code as

```
var gp:Point = new Point(e.stageX,e.stageY);  //global point
var lp:Point = uic.globalToLocal(gp); //local point
var lp2:Point = new Point(e.localX,e.localY);
var lp2:Point = uic.globalToLocal(gp);
```

now it is expected to have all the lp, lp2 and lp3 variables to be same but weiredly lp two is giving wrong value and lp2 and lp3 were giving correct. I am suspecting using the variable lp has something to do. I am not sure about that but above proves it so right now I am using lp2.

does any one know why is this behavior? is it a bug? or am I overseen something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly, I didn't look at your previous questions before leaving my comment :) I take it your questions seem to leave people quite perplex... It's probably due to the way you present them as totally abstract behaviors.

Taking the example above, I'm not sure you're going the right way about the globalToLocal method.

My understanding of globalToLocal is that given a Point and a DisplayObject, globalToLocal will return the position of the Point in relation to the DisplayObject.

```
      var pt:Point = new Point ( 10, 20 ); // x, y in relation to the Stage
      var shape:Shape = new Shape();
      shape.x = 10;
      shape.y = 30;

      // x, y should trace 0 , 10 , which is the position of the 
      //point in relation to shape.
      pt = shape.globalToLocal(pt );

      //or if you prefer to declare a new variable
      var pointToShape:Point = shape.globalToLocal(pt );
```

In your example you state that you're trying to get the local coordinates of uic , your UIComponent , when in fact you're only returning the values of your Mouse position in relation to uic. Then you state:

```
   "now it is expected to have all the lp, lp2 and lp3 variables to be the same "
```

No , because you keep redeclaring your variables:

```
   var lp2:Point = new Point(e.localX,e.localY);
   //the next declaration/statement cancels the previous one
   var lp2:Point = uic.globalToLocal(gp);
```

Please note that once a variable has been declared , it is not necessary to redeclare it in subsequent statements. In the example above , there's no relationships between the two lp2 declaration, you may as well write:

```
   var x:int = 10;
   x = 20;
   x = whatever;// each statement practically cancels the previous one.
```

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. I did not understand couple of points here. What you mean by
   // x, y should trace 0 , 10 , which is the position of the 
   //point in relation to shape.

x, y of what? point or shape? what ever it is how it can trace to 0,10, because point is 10,20 and shape is 10,20

second one, what I understand from the the "var x:int = 10" example you gave is that the globalToLocal is going to change the values of the point variables being passed as paramter? in my example, the gp is going to change whenever I pass it to globalToLocal function? I am going to test the snippets rightaway

Comment: i traced pt after globaltolocal conversion and got 0,-10 which is as expcected. traced pt and pointToShape after the last line, i got 0,-10 (pt unchanged as I expected) and -10,-40 which is what I did not get. why pointToShape is -10, -40, in what relation?

Comment: You're right, I wrote to fast, it should output 0, -10. Since you're passing pt as a parameter , changing pt's value will logically change the results of pointToShape.

Comment: oh yes, I have overseen that we are actually passing the new pt second time which is expected. however, it was not the same in my case. I was toggling mouseChildren and enableMouse of uic. I guess thats where it went wrong.